# Drupal 8: How to create completely standalone custom page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Good day,
I've been thrown in the deep DEEP end with a website I have to develop using Drupal 8 and the Acquia platform.

The problem is that the timeframe in which I have to develop this website is so small that there just isn't time to learn all the Drupal in's and out's.  My thinking is to create custom pages with custom html etc. and from there Ajax my way through this.

However having absolutely no Drupal experience this proves to be challenging as hell.

Is there any way I can create a custom page using a complete custom template bypassing the Drupal inner workings and just plug into the main objects such as the database etc.

I've been spending a lot of time on Google on how to achieve this but to no avail.  Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

So far I only installed the Bootstrap theme but can't seem to even find the files for this theme in my file structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Your question is too broad for stackoverflow. We're here to help with specific programming problems, not to guide you, neither to give you advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to page that explains how to create custom page (the module that gives you custom page, that is) in D8:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/a-hello-world-custom-page-module

You'll have to do some reading...but it's not that much.